# What does APPCOMMAND_LAUNCH_APP1 do?

Tags: windows, winapi

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-appcommand for reference.

I've just made a tool to send certain button presses to Windows and I came across this 'button'. It looks like something I could use, but I can't find anything about how it works. I've already tried sending it with my tool, but nothing happens. (I am able to successfully send commands like microphone mute and media play/pause, so my implementation is correct.)

What does APPCOMMAND_LAUNCH_APP1 do? What is app1 or how can I configure what app1 should be?

Comment: When you press one of the remappable Buttons that launches an application (as Calculator) in an extended KeyBoard, you get a `WM_APPCOMMAND` notification with that command in HI-LParam. -- User configuration / preferences.

Comment: Thanks! So where in Windows do I configure that e.g. Calculator should start up? I would like to change it to a custom application, if possible.

Comment: It's in the Registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey`). You should see a series of numbers there. For example `APPCOMMAND_LAUNCH_APP1 = 0x0011` (17). You can see a matching key to this command. All other keys corresponding to extended Keyboard launcher buttons are listed there, each with an associated application (or Shell Class, e.g., `html`). -- If you're really a bad person :), but cannot access the Registry, you can detect the Windows of the application just started, close it and run your own. -- Anyway, these are User preferences.

Comment: Ah thank you, now it checks out. I am seeing some of the other 'more hardcoded' commands like opening mail are also defined here. An evil master mind could 'jumble' these registry values muahaha~ Uhm, anyway. On my machine, app1 (17) is configured to open a Windows Explorer window and app2 (18) is configured to start calc.exe, however firing these commands at Windows through my custom application doesn't seem to work. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Those are notifications. The System notifies that the User took an action. Your app may be interested in what that action is and possibly act on it, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jimi said in the comments, the app1 and app2 applications are defined in the registry. By default it should be Windows Explorer for app1 and Calculator for app2, but it can be modified.

The registry key where these applications can be viewed / redefined is here:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey

The numbered keys in AppKey correspond to the command number of the WM_APPCOMMAND sent.

The value may be something like calc.exe if the application can be found in the PATH environment variable, but it may be the path to an executable as well. Even some special commands are supported that Windows will recognize as special folders. See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/CLSID-List.htm for special folder GUIDs.